Prevent figure* from starting a new page
In the bellow example, I wish to have the figure appear right after the first line of text. But instead it appears on a new page. What is the best way to prevent this from happening. Ideal I wish to use the same document class if possible.
figure* allows you to break the two column set up, but at the expense of starting the figure on a new page. I wish to prevent this.
\documentclass[aps,prb,preprintnumbers,amsmath,amssymb,superscriptaddress,twocolumn,10pt]{revtex4-2}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

Some sample text. I don't know how to force the figure to start right after this rather then on a new page.

\begin{figure*}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{IMG_0902.jpeg}
    \caption{This is a wide figure that spans both columns.}
    \label{fig:img1}
\end{figure*}

\lipsum

\end{document}



The image is too large to fit on the previous page.  You may need to rescale it.

@Nate I don't believe so. Even if I do \includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth]{IMG_0902.jpeg}, it still appears on the next page.
figure* allows you to break the two column set up, but at the expense of starting the figure on a new page.

Setting it to 0.1\textwidth doesn't mean it fits. Aren't you getting any warnings related to the figure size? You could also force it by using the "float" package, but its usually recommended to let latex position the figures.

@D.Quan I have no warnings related to the figure size.

Related/duplicate: Displaying a wide figure in a two-column document

@Werner As Stated in the problem, I do not wish to use the multicols package

@WaterDrop: Do you want the columns to be balanced above the figure insertion (so left and right columns line up), then the figure, then the rest of the text, balanced across the two columns? Or do you want the text flow to stay in column 1 across the figure, then column 2 across the figure again?

@Werner Correct, I am looking for the text above to balance, then an image, then a more text with balancing.

any particular reason you don't want to take the most obvious means to your end? also, if this is for submission to a journal (as the document class suggests), there are probably restrictions on what you are allowed to do here.

figure* will never appear on the page on which it is created.  The usual trick is to place it earlier in the text so that it winds up on the right page.  It also always goes to the top of the page.

Interestingly, revtex4-2 does not support \twocolumn[...] either.

I was able to get what I think you want by removing the twocolumn option in your document class and using the multicol package. I also had to switch to the extarticle documentclass since revtex4-2 evidently does not permit the use of the multicol package. I also switched to a png file that is present in TeXLive 2024.
This was compiled and works using lualatex.
Following is the MWE.
\documentclass[aps,prb,preprintnumbers,amsmath,amssymb,superscriptaddress,10pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/context/sample/common/mill.png}
    \caption{This is a wide figure that spans both columns.}
    \label{fig:img1}
\end{figure*}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum
\end{multicols}

\end{document}


Oops! I did not realize revtex was a documentclass for physics journals. So switching to extarticle is almost certainly not what you need.
